# The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'. Try making the call conditional (using '?.')

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I want to call the data from API using horizontal_data_table on flutter. this is the code where it gets the error

```
       Container(
          width: 200,
          height: 52,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 0, 0),
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: Text(widget.leavelistmodel.response[index].paidLeaveEmployeeNip),
        ),
```

and the data model from the result looks like this:

```
class LeaveListResult {
  int? paidLeaveId;
  String? paidLeaveEmployeeNip;
  String? paidLeaveEmployeeFullName;
}
```

I'm already changing it into? and ! it still got an error, how can I fix the error?

Answer (score 1):

We used `nullSafty` for the model variable. `?`

```
class LeaveListResult {
  int? paidLeaveId;
  String? paidLeaveEmployeeNip;
  String? paidLeaveEmployeeFullName;
}
```

Since it is the same as Swift's optional, nullSafty must be canceled.

```
Container(
          width: 200,
          height: 52,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 0, 0),
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: Text(widget.leavelistmodel.response[index].paidLeaveEmployeeNip ?? 'NULL'),
        ),
```

You can force unwrapping with `!`, but this is not a good practice. The reason is that an error occurs when it is null. When it is null by using `channing`, an exception handling message should be displayed instead of an error.

Answer (score 1):

the `Text` can't accept a nullable `String?`, if you're sure that your data isn't `null` then do this:

```
  child: Text(widget.leavelistmodel!.response[index]!.paidLeaveEmployeeNip),
```

you can also set a default value for the `String?` that will be shown when it's `null` :

```
  child: Text(widget.leavelistmodel?.response[index]?.paidLeaveEmployeeNip ?? "default value"),
```

Answer (score 0):

The `response` can be null on this case. You can check the null value and then move forward. As for `paidLeaveEmployeeNip`  filed also a nullable String but Text widget doesnt accept null value. You can directly accept null string

```dart
 child: Text("${widget.leavelistmodel.response?[index].paidLeaveEmployeeNip}"),
```

Or for default value

```dart
Text(widget.leavelistmodel.response?[index].paidLeaveEmployeeNip ?? "Got Null")
```